# Edit php.ini file using DirectAdmin

Tags: php, directadmin

I want to edit my `php.ini` file to allow file uploads. Running `phpinfo()` tells me that it is located at `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`. However, I am paying for hosting and can only make these changes via [DirectAdmin](http://www.directadmin.com/).

How can I make the change I need to make to my PHP config using DirectAdmin?

Comment: are you using shared hosting?

Comment: Why do you believe you need to do anything in php.ini to upload files?

Comment: @Adam I have no idea, i just bought my webhosting at a site.

Comment: @deceze because w3schools said: "In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:"  , so thats why i look for it.

Comment: As Adam write if you using shared hosting, you probably can't access php.ini file

Comment: Is it currently *disabled*? Unlikely, unless you have an extremely restrictive host.

Comment: @deceze i asked it to my webhoster, and they said its on. So this problem is solved

Comment: <domain>:2222/CMD_PLUGINS/phpselector/index.html#/options

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if the php.ini file is located on a shared host and the administrator is not willing to make changes (which often is the case) you can create a ".user.ini" file with the following settings to allow uploading of files. Just adjust the values to your requirements.

```
max_execution_time = value
max_input_time = value
post_max_size = value
upload_max_filesize = value
memory_limit = value
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ubuntu server, php.ini file is found in apache2 dir

Open php ini file

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

And change `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in order to increase uploaded file size limit.

Next restart apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now check `phpinfo()`